# apply DRY with entityContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dry

I am having some trouble to respect the DRY principle, when implementing EntityFramework DBContext related function.

In details, I have a SelectClient function :

```
public static Client SelectClientFromID(String ClientID)
    {
        using (DBContext SaveContext = new DBContext())
        {
            try
            {
                SaveContext.MyCompanies.Load();
                SaveContext.MyProjects.Load();
                SaveContext.MyClient.Load();
                return SaveContext.MyClient.Where(x => x.ClientID.ToString() == ClientID).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to have a DeleteClient function, for now it looks like that :

```
public static void DeleteClient(Client client)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DBContext SaveContext = new DBContext())
            {
                SaveContext.MyCompanies.Load();
                SaveContext.MyProjects.Load();
                SaveContext.MyClient.Load();
                Client savedClient = SaveContext.MyClient.Where(x => x.ClientID == client.ClientID).FirstOrDefault();
                SaveContext.MyClient.Remove(savedClient);
                SaveContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

To follow the DRY principle I would have like to instead call my `SelectClientFromID` function, and use my `SaveContext.MyClient.Remove(savedClient)` with `savedClient` being the return from my `SelectClientID` function.
Sadly, as my Client would come from another `DBContext`, it does not work.
How should I do to properly implements my functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take your time and read about Repository pattern/Unit of work pattern. It solves your problem by having a common DbContext instance across all repositories of your entities.

Comment: Hum, I just finish reading http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/581487/Unit-of-Work-Design-Pattern but it seems to me that my Unit of Work already is my DBContext.  It would seem dangerous to create a global DBContext, do you have any documentation with more detailed explaination ?

Comment: @Belterius http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application here's a good article